# SpriteKit scale for universal app

Tags: iphone, ipad, sprite-kit, universal, ios-universal-app

What is the best practice to universal app?

Make iPad version and them scale to iPhone ? is a good idea?

```
 if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
            viewSize.height *= 2;
            viewSize.width *= 2;
        }
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Well, it depends upon the game. If you literally want to scale the sprites, a factor of 2.4 will be more applicable.

Comment: hmm what if i first make iPhone version ? and scale up to iPad? apple approve that ?

Comment: Definitely. It will be much easier to implement as well.

Comment: but when i scaled iphone version to iPad the quality image is not to bad?

Comment: The images will have to be made for ipad, even for the iphone version

Comment: Summarising:
- I make image with iPad size
- Make iphone version first
- And Scale iPhone version to iPad using: SKScene* scene = [[SKScene alloc] initWithSize:CGSizeMake(skView.bounds.size.width/2.4, skView.bounds.size.height/2.4)

Comment: Yes. This should work. If not, you could set up a method which explicitly calculates the size depending upon the device.

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial will be very useful for you .

http://www.raywenderlich.com/49695/sprite-kit-tutorial-making-a-universal-app-part-1
http://www.raywenderlich.com/49697/sprite-kit-tutorial-making-a-universal-app-part-2

I'm sure that it will make your apps better